# How to add google results for a given search string to a website

Tags: integration, google-search

the thing is, I have some given words and I want to search through my website for them, and display them to the user, but without the user entering any stuff.

Thanks so far!

**UPDATE**

and it should not be an iFrame ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well ...

I found quite an easy solution, which is actually provided by google itself: http://www.google.com/cse/manage/create

it does not run in an iframe as well. I like it pretty much ;-)